# Only the top dropdown is populating corectly. Need the same functionality with other dropdowns as well

Tags: javascript, jquery

my goal is to add dropdown on button click. the first dropdown lets me select a sub-dropdown. it's working correctly. but when i add another drop down, it fails. The add button with add another dropdrop with the exact same functionality as the first dropdown.

here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="mydropdown">
    <div id="dropdown"
        <label for="xyz" >xyz</label>
            <select id="id_xyz" name="xyz_id">
                            <option>--Select -</option>
                              <option value="v1">op1</option>
                                <option value="v2">op2</option>
                        </select>

                    <select id="v1" name="t1" style="display:none" class="sub_content"> 
                        <option>-Sub1-</option>
                         <option>option2</option>
                         <option>option3</option>
                         <option>option4</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="v2" name="t2" style="display:none" class="sub_content"> 
                        <option>-Sub2-</option>
                        <option>option1</option>
                         <option>option2</option>
                         <option>option3</option>
                         <option>option4</option>
                    </select>

                        <button class="add_button" id="add">Add </button>
                        <button class="add_button" id="remove" style="display:none;">remove </button>

    </div>
    </div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#id_xyz").change(function(){
                var v = $(this).val();
                var y = $("#"+v);
                if (v != ''){
                $('.sub_content').hide();
                 y.show();
                 }

                });
            }); 

        $(document).ready(function(){
                var counter =2;
                $("#add").click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var $newdiv = $('#dropdown').clone();
                var newvert =        $(document.createElement('div')).after("id", 'dropdown' + counter);
                $('div.mydropdown').append($newdiv);
                $("#remove").show();
                });
            });
```

here's the link to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/deerups/HQUMF/

Comment: Why 2 document ready?

Comment: You're cloning yourself and it looks like you just need to bind new click handlers to the freshly cloned Add/Remove buttons.

Comment: don't write random answers if you don't know what you are saying.. it's tempting to jump into a discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When cloning your value, clone it with a `true` parameter :

```
var $newdiv = $('#dropdown').clone(true);
```

Passing `true` mean "cloning events" : http://api.jquery.com/clone/;

Then change your `.change()` function for that :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#id_xyz").change(function(){
        var v = $(this).find(':selected').val();
        if (v){
            var y = $(this).closest('#dropdown').find("#"+v);
            y.siblings('.sub_content').addBack().hide();
            y.show();
        }else{
            $(this).closest('#dropdown').find('.sub_content').hide()
        }
    });
});
```

That will allow you to change the dropdown next to the changing drop instead of the first one.

Side note, never duplicate an id.

Comment: Your event delegation wouldn't work, because the `id` is changed for each cloned element...

Comment: In his case, he never change the id. But yeah, it wouldnt work if he do change the id.

Comment: Oops, I misread his code. There's a part where it looked like he was changing the `id` of the cloned element (which he should be doing), but it's not what he's actually doing

Comment: this is not very helpful. I like to change the name of the each dropdown class that's added. that'll help be track the dropdown divs.

Comment: @Acer_Racer, Im a little bit confused by your question, changed my answer, maybe it is the good one?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon thanks for trying, but that's not what i was looking for. the goal is to clicking add button will display another similar dropdown with the same select options.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon next step is to add a counter to div id and change the div id name from "id_xyz" to id_xyz1, id_xyz2 ..etc for each div that is added. can you help with this?

Comment: @Acer_Racer here : http://jsfiddle.net/HQUMF/4/ just look before the append, i added some code

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon I am wondering if i can change the id name from dropdown to dropdown1, dropdown2 etc after cloning.. so that it'll help me with the delete functionality. when i delete a particular dropdown, i can just day (#particulardropdown).hide(). can it be done?

Comment: Yes you can, but for delete, you are better with `.closest()` function : http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon thanks a lot. I used .closest() to remove. love you.